# Azure Toolkit for Intellij plugin incorrectly shows "No subscriptions" after Azure device logon

Tags: intellij-idea, azure-java-tools

I have 2 Azure accounts both have subscription which I can see via portal.azure.com but when I login via the plugin on Intellij it claims I have no subscriptions which is blocking my use of the toolkit.

I'm using Intellij Ultimate 2019.3.5

Answer (score -1):

thanks a lot for this question. I'm from Azure Toolkit product team and we have seen this case happening for a few time.

1. Login with Azure CLI might help you bypass this issue.
2. If you verified that you have logged in with correct account using device login, pleas contact azure-java-tools@microsoft.com and we are happy to help investigate.